# Extracting common interfaces from two projects to a shared project

Tags: kotlin

I have two projects that have several classes and interfaces in common.
I am trying to move the common stuff to a different project and share it with the other two projects. Let's call them:

Project A
Project B
Project Common

Project A and B have an interface with different methods like:

**Project A**

```
interface Foo {
    fun screen1InProjectA()
    fun screen2InProjectA()
}
```

**Project B**

```
interface Foo {
    fun screen1InProjectB()
    fun screen2InProjectB()
}
```

I also have the following interface that is the same in both project A and B.

```
interface ContractFoo {
  fun screen(to: Foo.() -> Unit)
}
```

I'd like to move interface *ContractFoo* to my Project Common,
but it has a *Foo* dependency, and Project Common doesn't and shouldn't have access to Projects A and B.
Is there a way to modify the Foo interfaces so I can move the *ContractFoo* to Project Common?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have 2 options.

**1. Use generics**

```kotlin
interface Contract<T> {
    fun screen(to: T.() -> Unit)
}
```

Of course this opens the possibility of having `Contract` of anything even that it is not a `Foo`.

**2. Add `Foo` interface to Project Common**

You could have a marker interface `Foo` in Project Common as follows:

```kotlin
interface Foo { }
```

That you would extend in each of the Projects:

```kotlin
interface FooA : Foo {
    fun screen1InProjectA()
    fun screen2InProjectA()
}
```

```kotlin
interface FooB : Foo {
    fun screen1InProjectB()
    fun screen2InProjectB()
}
```

I would go with 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the second approach, but then when I use the screen1InProjectB() for example in projects A and B, the compiler says "Unresolved reference: screen1InProjectB()" and I don't know how to solve this

Comment: That is because you are referencing the variable as a `Foo` that does not have `screen1InProjectB()` method. You need to reference it as `FooB`.